# Running cucumber + watir-webdriver + mac os x over SSH gives "Element cannot be scrolled into view"

Tags: firefox, cucumber, jenkins, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a cucumber project using watir-webdriver and headless that works just fine on my mac workstation.  I have set up a special "jenkins" user on my workstation that owns this project as I intend to convert my workstation to a Jenkins node.  When running the tests over the command line as the "jenkins" user, or over my local Jenkins install, it all works fine.

However, when I SSH into my workstation from a remote Unix box and I try to run cucumber from the command line some of my tests return:

```
Element cannot be scrolled into view:http://[url] (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError)
```

Here is my env.rb snippet that sets up the browser:

```
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start

require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

Before do
  @browser = browser
end

# "after all"
at_exit do
  browser.close
  headless.destroy
end
```

Interestingly, some tests still pass and cucumber still generates screenshots so over SSH cucumber is still opening firefox, succeeding in some tests, taking screenshots and closing down.

**Update**: Created a new Jenkins slave on Ubuntu host with exact same settings/install/project and it works just fine.  Seemingly confirms this is a X11 on Mac OSX Lion issue.  Maybe the port to xquartz for Mountain Lion will help.

Comment: First thing I would try is to force the browser into focus while running (and give it some size so you can see). I have had trouble in the past running tests on minimized browsers. You may also check the jenkins user's permissions. Just some ideas.

Comment: Interesting - forcing the browser into focus makes it work.  I'll post my env.rb to see how I'm setting up the browser

Comment: What version of selenium-webdriver do you have installed? If not the latest (2.18), try upgrading to that and see if it helps.

Comment: I have selenium-webdriver of 2.18 and watir-webdriver 0.5.2, firewatir 1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

I have not used headless for testing. Alister Scott had an example of it in [his blog](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/) and it did NOT use firefox.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
headless = Headless.new
headless.start
b = Watir::Browser.start 'www.google.com'
puts b.title
b.close
headless.destroy
```

You should add the following code to your env.rb file:

```
if ENV['HEADLESS']
  require 'headless'
  headless = Headless.new
  headless.start
  at_exit do
    headless.destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Dave.  Have tried not specifying a browser, it still uses by firefox by default.

Comment: Your session is started differently. Alister has Browser.start while you have Browser.new. Maybe you tried it exactly like that already, but you should if you did not.

Comment: Made no difference I'm afraid Dave

Answer (score 0):

You may be suffering from this bug in Selenium / WebDriver:

[Selenium Webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3075)

They are working on it; turning on native events helps on some platforms / browsers.

Comment: I don't think so - I have created a new slave using ubuntu and it works successfully.